# System.out.printf not printing integer arguments

Tags: java, string-formatting

I'm new to java programming and I'm having trouble returning a method from another class. Both classes compile and run successfully. I'm able to call a simple int from one of the classes but when I want to calculate two input integers that the user has inputted I just get a blank space.

This is my calculations class

```
class calculations {
    public final int AGE = 53;
    public int numbers(int num1, int num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Here's my user class. I can get the `AGE` variable to print but the `numbers()` method doesn't return a value. It's just a blank space.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class user {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        int i1, i2;

        System.out.println("Enter int1: ");
        i1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter int2: ");
        i2 = input.nextInt();

        calculations kjc = new calculations();

        System.out.printf("Age = " + kjc.AGE);

        System.out.printf("\nints: " , i1, i2, kjc.numbers(i1, i2));

    }
}
```

If anyone can explain why `System.out.printf("\nints: " , i1, i2, kjc.numbers(i1, i2));` doesn't print out the calculations of the two input ints.

Comment: `System.out.println("ints: " + i1 + ", " + i2 + ", " + kjc.numbers(i1, i2));` or `System.out.printf("\nints: %d, %d, %d", i1, i2, kjc.numbers(i1, i2));`

Comment: I would just like to point out that by convention, we Java programmers have decided that we'll always capitalize the first letter of a class name. So, try to make it a habit and name your classes `Calculations` and `User` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You're using printf but you have zero format specifiers.

Try this

```
 System.out.printf("\nints: %d, %d, %d" , i1, i2, kjc.numbers ( i1,i2 ));
```

Basically, each argument after the first string is matched sequentially to each format specifier. `%d` is the format specifier for a decimal integer

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't print the two inputs added together. I still get a blank space.

Comment: Instead of using commas, just use the plus sign to concatenate it all

Comment: @SearchingFor You did not copy the code correctly. Please paste your modified code up in your question

Answer (score 1):

To be simple you can also print using:

```
System.out.println("\nints: ,"+ i1 +", "+i2+","+ kjc.numbers()");
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you could also use `String.format` function too.

```
String str = String.format("I was born in %d", 2015);
System.out.println(str);
```